# Kalman Filter on a set of points belonging to the same object?

Tags: opencv3.0, kalman-filter

Let's say you're tracking a set of 20 segments with the same length belonging to the same 3D plane.

To visualize, imagine that you're drawing a set of segments of length 10 cm randomly on a sheet of paper. And make someone move this sheet in front of the camera.

Let's say those segments are represented by two points `A` and `B`.
Let's assume we manage to track `A_t` and `B_t` for all the segments. The tracked points aren't stable from frame to frame resulting in occasional jitter which might be solved by a Kalman filter.

My questions are concerning the state vector:

- A Kalman filter for `A` and `B` for each segment (with 20 segments this results in 40 KF) is an obvious solution but it looks too heavy (knowing that this should run in real-time).
- Since all the tracked points have the same properties (belonging to the same 3D plane, have the same length) isn't it possible to create one big KF with all those variables?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Runtime: keep in mind that the kalman equations involve matrix multiplications and one inversion. So having 40 states means having some 40x40 matrices. That will always take longer to calculate than running 40 one-state filters, where your matrices are 1x1 (scalar). Anyway, running the big filter only makes sense if you do know of a mathematical relationship between your states (=correlation), otherwise its output wise the same like running the 40 one-state filters.
2. With the information given thats really hard to tell. E.g. if your segments are always a polyline you could describe that differently in contrast to knowing nothing about the shape.